# How to throw user to a page other than /login if user is not authenticated in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I wanted to throw users out on signup page instead of login page when they are not authenticated. One workaroud I did was to pass "/signup" in .loginPage() function in Security configuration of spring boot application.

But now I also need to put a .rememberMe() feature for login page. because of that I have to pass "/login" in .loginPage(). So that I can add .rememberMe() functionality.

To summarize, How can I throw non-authenticated users to /signup page as well as keeping the rememberMe functionality on login page?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
       http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/game*/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/contest*/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/badges_awards").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/admin*/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("emailAddress")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()  
                .rememberMe()  
                .key("remember-me")  
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .rememberMeCookieName("rememberlogin")
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your configuration like this to tell Spring Security that `/signup` URL does not need authentication and therefore won't be redirect to your login page :

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login.html").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/signup*/**").permitAll()
.and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .failureHandler(LoginAuthFailureHandler)
.and()
    .exceptionHandling()
    .accessDeniedPage("/signup.html");
```

}

@Component
public class LoginAuthFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/signup.html");

}
```

}

Comment: I tried this but didn't really work. but when I tried putting .authenticationEntryPoint(customHandler()) to exceptionHandling() instead of .accessDeniedPage. Then it worked for me.